# Keep browser in loading state until the end of onLoad/Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, browser

I am executing an ajax query to retrieve data from another webpage form.
Because my ajax call get data and changes the DOM, I need to wait until it is resolved to tell to other tools that would use my webpage that my page has finished loading.

I saw that there are properties like `ready` and `readyState`, but they seem to be read-only properties.
Other solutions that were on StackOverflow suggested to "fake" a loading state by showing a loading image, but I need a real loading state.

Any way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

I´d prefer a kind of "self-written" state.
Use a variable to count the loaded fragments of your page.
If you have 3 fragments, which are loaded by ajax and then inserted in the DOM, count the variable up each time an ajax-call completet.
After each completed AJAX-call look at this counter. If it reached 3 (in this example), you can go on with your "onLoad"-Method.

it would be something like this:

```
var globCounter = 0;
var amountOfFragments = 3;
$.ajax(...some stuff here...).done(doneFunction);
function doneFunction(){
    globCounter++;
    if(globCounter === amountOfFragments){
         runYourOnLoadFunctionHere();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it. However, I don't think it will keep the browser in the loading state (maybe I'm wrong ?).
I don't mind about when my onLoad function or Ajax call is executed. What interests me is that the browser wait until the end of the Ajax call (or onLoad function) before entering the loaded state(or complete in the case of readyState).

Comment: Oh - ok. So i think i missunderstood the question. It´s about an external trigger by the browser after the page is completely loaded? I think you could use some server-side script, which will be loaded by the page. This server-side script must be blocked, as long as all stuff of the page is loaded, and you decide to be ready. After this, you´d have to tell the server to release this script, maybe in just returning an empty string or something like this...

Comment: It may be an external trigger after the page is completely loaded yes, but I don't have control over it. It could for example using this tool from [Google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/mobile-friendly/) to check if my website is mobile-friendly. It displays wrong results because, at the time their evaluation occurs, my page is in the ready state but neither the javascript modifications nor the ajax call has ended. That my problem, I would want this kind of website to wait until my page is completely loaded (i.e. Ajax and javascript DOM modifications).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fake extension of the DOM loaded state for the browser.  Once the browser parses the entire HTML document and finishes loading all stylesheets (`<link>` tags) and loading and executing all external javascript files  (`<script>` tags), the `window.onload` function is called, if assigned.

AJAX requests are asynchronous.  While they can be started before the DOM is fully loaded, you can't guarantee that they response will come back before the DOM is loaded.  To accomplish what you want (wait until the DOM is loaded AND your Ajax request finishes to trigger other functions), you'd have to check the state of both periodically.  Then you could trigger a custom event, that you can bind to various places in your javascript code, so you don't have to have all your custom `onLoad` code in one place.

Example:

```js
var documentLoaded = false;
var ajaxLoaded = false;
$(document).ready( function() {
  documentLoaded = true;
});

function simulateAjaxLoad() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#ajax-content').html('Ajax Content Loaded');
    ajaxLoaded = true;
   }, 1000);
}

// asynchronous start the AJAX request before the DOM finishes loading
simulateAjaxLoad(); 

// periodically check for DOM ready and Ajax loaded
var loadStateTimer = setInterval( function() {
  if(documentLoaded && ajaxLoaded) {
    $(document).trigger('good-to-go'); // custom event
    clearInterval(loadStateTimer); // stop checking, we're fully loaded
  }
}, 100);

// utility function to log progress
function log(message) {
  var logger = $('#log');
  logger.html(logger.html() + message + "<br>");
}

// handle the custom event here
$(document).on('good-to-go', function () {
  log("good-to-go event handled");
  // some on-load code here
});

// ...

// handle the custom event somewhere else
$(document).on('good-to-go', function () {
  log("good-to-go event handled here too");
  // some other on-load code here
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#ajax-content {
  background: #eee;
  min-height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ajax-content"></div>
<div id="log"></div>
```